# how to db:migrate after restoring database from mysql dump in docker

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker containers for `mysql` and `ruby` and the `ruby` container is dependent on `mysql` container.

In my `docker-compose`, I have volume-mounted an sql dump to the `mysql` container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` so that it gets executed upon starting the container for the first time and the database gets populated with some data.

The sql dump gets executed and the data gets restored to the db container as expected, but the problem is, while starting the `ruby` (with rails) container, it throws out a `migration pending error`. I understand that this is happening because there is no any schema migration versions recorded in the `schema_migrations` table as the data was deliberately restored from the sql dump.

But, even running `docker-compose run <container> rake db:migrate` wouldn't help because it throws out a `table already exists` error as the tables have already been created.

How do I sync the rails schema migration versions with the actual data in the database?

I've also tried by manually adding the latest schema version number to the `schema_migrations` table but still returns `migration pending error`. And, I cannot run `docker-compose run <container> rake db:create db:migrate` before restoring from sql dump because the files inside the container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will only be executed if the database isn't created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can dump all data inside `schema_migrations` along with your initial dump schema, so that it will contain the migration versions and it won't raise an exception upon running `rails db:migrate`.

Update:
The older version of rails actually checks all schema versions to decide whether it needs migration or not. You can check [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L854-L856) for more info.

```rb
      def needs_migration?(connection = Base.connection)
        (migrations(migrations_paths).collect(&:version) - get_all_versions(connection)).size > 0
      end
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks! turns out we also need to dump all the schema versions recorded in the `schema_migrations` table. Initially, I only tried by dumping the latest recent version.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `bundle exec rake db:migrate` inside your docker_entrypoint file.

Comment: do you mean in the .sql dump?

Comment: you can write inside your docker_entrypoint file which will execute when you run docker-compose up